# Jenkins - Execute same model sequentially, not parallel

Tags: matrix, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have multiple hardwares (A, B, C) and each one of them have two software versions (1, 2).
I want Jenkins to execute test on same hardware with both software versions, but sequentially.
Currently my execution matrix look like this:

```
-----------------------------
A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2, C_1, C_2
-----------------------------
```

I want my execution matrix should look like the following:

```
--------------
A_1, B_1, C_1
--------------
A_2, B_2, C_2
--------------
```

First run tests on all hardware with software version 1, 
then run tests on all hardware with software version 2.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: How many Jenkins slave do you have or Is it all connected to once slave?

Comment: I have many jenkins slaves, more than the number of hardware/software

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to have separate jobs for `A_1, B_1, C_1,A_2, B_2, C_2`. If so :

**Option 1:**

Use existing Jenkins Feature

> Click Customize your Jenkins job
>   Build Triggers > Build after other Projects are built.

you can mention which projects needs to be watched and you have multiple options such as

> Trigger only if the build is stable
>   Trigger even if the build is not stable
>   Trigger even if the build fails

[image]

**OPTION 2**:

Use `Build other projects` option in post-build action of each job.
[image]

For example in your case in job `A_1` go to configuration and add job `B_1` in `projects to build` in post-build action and similarly do this for other job as per your requirement. So once job `A_1` is finished it will trigger `B_1` and once `B_1` is finished it will trigger `C_1`, similarly for `A_2, B_2 and C_2`.

**OPTION 3:**

Use [Multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) Plugin.